# Do LDO voltage regulators need a diode on VCC?

Tags: diodes, ldo

I'd like to know if my application of an LDO regulator really requires a diode on its voltage source for protection?  I originally added it just to ensure current only flowed into the regulator's VCC and not out of it.

I am using the LDO regulator because my voltage source and regulator output are pretty close to each other 14.6V and 12.6V.  Once I add the diode they become even closer.

I will add this is generally a pretty electrically noisy environment.  And the specific regulator I am using is LT3042EDD#PBF.  Although I am more asking for guidance in general if and when a diode should be used before LDO regulator VCC.

[image: circuit]

Comment: You might want to elaborate what you intend the purpose of the diode to be because it is not immediately obvious. It sounds like you're just talking about it as if it is a given but it's not.

Comment: Where do you propose this diode be placed? An output to input diode is used if there's a risk of the regulator being backpowered and the regulator in question can't handle that on its own, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Now that you've edited it: Why do you think current could flow out of the regulator's input?

Comment: Do you have a reason you believe that current inherently will try to flow backwards through the LDO? I'm not saying it never will or can't. I'm saying that whether or not you need to actually worry about that depends on the circuit and the LDO architecture itself.

Comment: In other words, what problem (perceived or otherwise) is the diode trying to solve?

Comment: I don't have a reason to believe current will flow out of input, I am just trying to ensure I don't damage the regulator.  I usually put diodes infront of ICs that are connected to a voltage line with many consumers.  This is partly due to inexperience.

Comment: How could the regulator become damaged do you think? Maybe you are trying to implement reverse polarity protection or maybe it's something else. I think if you read the comments, everyone is confused as to why you think it's important.

Comment: It depends what scenarios you expect. The diode might be useful if there is a chance that when device is powered and running, something shorts the input to ground.

Comment: @Andyaka take this with a grain of salt.  But I have a battery connected to output of LDO and if my input fell below 12V maybe there was the potential for current to flow from my battery to the input voltage source?

Comment: @Feynman137 Don't stick diodes in random places--all you're doing is wasting energy and potentially worsening ESD withstand performance. There may be situations where a diode placed like that is necessary, for instance if you want reverse input protection (though there are better ways to do that too). Definitely don't put a diode on the input to every single IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a linear regulator (I'm talking about all linear regulators here, not just LDOs) prevents reverse current flow on its own depends on its architecture (mainly it's pass transistor. If I'm not mistaken, BJT pass transistors can block reverse current flow but MOSFET pass transistors cannot (unless the designers go out of their way to do it). There was a very visual and informative web page online from a company illustrating the different pass architectures and how they would behave in reverse current situations but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

The load side pushing current backwards through the regulator (load-dumping) is only a problem for some circuits and is thus only a concern for those circuits. This might occur, for example, when the input voltage to the regulator gets reduced during shutoff and there is a huge amount of charged capacitance (or perhaps a spinning motor) on the load side that can push current backwards through the regulator.

If you need it, you need it. If you don't, you don't.

If the extra cost doesn't matter and you can tolerate the dropout the diode just takes some of the heat load off the regulator.

In other cases the diode might be there to prevent a momentary voltage sag from a much more powerful system (like a motor) from drawing charge out of the regulator's output capacitors backwards through the regulator, or its input capacitors, thus causing a brownout when that stored charge would have otherwise tided over the regulator and its load.

Also note, that load-dumping (reverse current due to the load) is not the same thing as reverse polarity where someone hooks up the power terminals backwards. If that's what you want to protect against, you'll want a diode (or some other method) regardless of the linear regulator architecture.

EDIT: Not the link I had in mind but mostly sufficient: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/ldo-basics-preventing-reverse-current-in-ldos